# Разной длины текст в блоке толкает контент

Tags: css, grid

Всем привет, ребят, подскажите, есть три блока, в котором есть текст разной длины, нужно сделать так, чтобы если в одном текст длиннее, то и в остальных двух блока одинаково толкался контент, для понимаю прикладываю ссылку на кодпен и скрин[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[пример](https://codepen.io/Wink/pen/VwWPZmz?editors=1100)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
  & + .col {
    margin-left: 24px;
  }
}

.header {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  // width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="header">
      <p>Title 1</p>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Some text long Some text long Some text long Some text long Some text long Some</p>
        <div class="button">
        Click me
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="list">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="header">
      <p>Title 2</p>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Some text long Some text long</p>
        <div class="button">
        Click me
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="list">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="header">
      <p>Title 3</p>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Some text long Some text </p>
        <div class="button">
        Click me
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="list">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В вашем примере используется flex, а в метках вопроса указано еще (и только) grid. В связи с этим уточняющий вопрос, приемлемы ли решения с использованием javascript?

Comment: css в приоритете конечно, но если можно, то и пример с js не помешает

Comment: И grid-, и flex-лейауты имеют дело с непосредственными наследниками контейнера. В вашем случае это блоки в красной рамочке. То что внутри них — уже само по себе. Можно только задать одинаковые фиксированные пропорции или высоты. Если нужна синхронизация по вычисленной высоте, то это будет js так или иначе.

Comment: честно говоря, я когда то сталкивался с подобным решением, было сделано через css, но найти пример уже не могу, там была похожая ситуация, только без синего блока внизу, и там пропорционально менялась высота у блока

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем, идея такая: делаем grid-лейаут и добавляем `.col { display:contents }`, чтобы сохранить вашу семантику карточек. Красную рамочку рисуем у наследников .col — из двух частей (верхней и нижней):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 0 10px;
}

.col {
  display:contents;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  padding:10px 10px 0 10px;
  border-color:red;
  border-width:1px 1px 0 1px;
  border-style: solid; 
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header > p { background-color: lightgreen; padding: 10px 10px 0 10px }

.main {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  justify-content: stretch;
  border-color:red;
  border-width:0 1px 1px 1px;
  border-style: solid; 
  padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  // width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: auto;
  position:relative;
  bottom:-4px;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex-grow:1;
  padding:10px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.content > p { padding:10px; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="header">
      <p>Title 1</p>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Some text long Some text long Some text long Some text long Some text long Some</p>
        <div class="button">
        Click me
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="list">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="header">
      <p>Title 2</p>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Some text long Some text long</p>
        <div class="button">
        Click me
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="list">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="header">
      <p>Title 3</p>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Some text long Some text </p>
        <div class="button">
        Click me
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="list">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а условный паддинг `padding`?

Comment: @highpassion Вообще никакой проблемы — перенес фоновые цвета на вложенные элементы. Это уже тюнинг, суть была в выравнивании по сетке элементов второго уровня вложенности. Т.к. subgrid работает только в FF (3%), то используется хак с display:contents